# How to emulate union mount behaviour with LVM in CentOS?

Tags: centos6, lvm, aufs

In short, I want to create a system restore image. My idea with AUFS is like the image below[image: AUFS union root]

Now, as I require this mount setup at boot-time, I don't think I can do it with *fuse* and will require AUFS kernel support, which, CentOS 6.x doesn't have. So I started to think along an alternative approach with **LVM snapshots**. The setup I have in mind is like following image[image: LVM snapshot mount]

However, I have a few questions about this setup.

1. Is this kind of setup at all possible with LVM or device mapper? If yes, how to do it?
2. with LVM, is it guaranteed to have write-protection in physical volume for read-only snapshots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yes.](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, the article you've linked to elaborates on how to implement a CoW docker backend. How do I do it with a physical machine, i.e. if I want the machine to boot with the aforesaid mount setup?

Comment: I don't see why not. Though you're probably reinventing the wheel. Look into [atomic updates](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/os-updates/), for instance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, as you've pointed out, this setup seems possible. I've tested this kind of setup with device-mapper snapshot target but with files loop-mounted as block device and on some non-root (e.g. `/mnt/dm_mount` rather than `/` itself) mount point. I can't figure out how to do it in boot-time and with `/` mount point. Can you please post an answer for that?